# How to get the exact url of the requests library in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using requests library of python and making a request like this

```
r = requests.get(solrShard1, params = solrParams)
```

Now i want to get the exact url the requests library is creating . I have tried using

```
req = requests.Request('POST',solrShard1, params = solrParams)
prepared = req.prepare()
print >>sys.stderr, "REQUEST START"
print >>sys.stderr, req.url
print >>sys.stderr, "REQUEST END"
```

but it only prints the url and not the exact url along with parameters and everything . How can i get the exact URL

Comment: You are making a POST call. In a POST call, the parameters are not appended to the URL. In a GET call, yes.

Comment: @JRodDynamite I did try with GET to but it still doesn't print the url with the parameters

Comment: I tried and it works for me:
req = requests.Request('POST', 'http://google.com', params={'param1': 10});
prep = req.prepare();
print(prep.url);

>> 'http://google.com/?param1=10'

Comment: If you set the 'data' argument instead of the 'params' argument it doesn't work.

Comment: @danielfranca yeah it does . i was printing req.url instead of prepared.url .

Comment: @EvanRoot yes, I noticed that while comparing my code and yours :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are showing the url from request object, instead of the prepared object.

The call to the `prepare` method doesn't mutate the object itself, instead it returns the prepared object, which you are already assigning to the `prepared`variable, but you are not using it anywhere.

Just change your code for the following and it should work:

```
print >>sys.stderr, "REQUEST START"
print >>sys.stderr, prepared.url
print >>sys.stderr, "REQUEST END"
```

I tried the code below and it works fine for me:

```
req = requests.Request('POST', 'http://google.com', params={'param1': 10})
prep = req.prepare()
print(prep.url)

>> 'http://google.com/?param1=10'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a POST request. In a POST request you do not have any parameters in the url but in the request body.

Try to print the request body with:

```
print(prepared.data)
```